# Cannot load c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: php, apache, wamp

State of services:

The service 'wampapache64' is NOT started
EXIT error code:1066
Help message for error code 1066 is:The service has returned a service-specific error code.

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 202 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.54.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found.     .

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 204 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.54.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found.     .

The service 'wampmysqld64' is started
Start type : DEMAND_START
Service Session : LocalSystem

The service 'wampmariadb64' is started
Start type : DEMAND_START
Service Session : LocalSystem

WampServer (Apache, PHP and MySQL) will not function properly if any service
'wampapache64'
'wampmysqld64'
'wampmariadb64'
is not started.

```
all services BINARY_PATH_NAME are OK
all services START_TYPE are OK
```

I have this problem/warning everytime starting wampserver, i double checked for the typo in httpd.conf file and locate the php2apache2_4.dll file, it did not typo, and the apache file is there, i got so confused

well i expected to not be a warning so that i can use my localhost/phpmyadmin, altough i already used another application for managing my localhost

Comment: OK, so is this a vanilla install of WAMPServer or have you made any changes?

Comment: You could show use the content of `httpd.conf` around the line 202 area so we can see what it is that is there